# While Loop Counter Does Not Stop

Tags: python, while-loop, counter, python-2.x

```
def individual_question_scores_pretest():
    question_number = 1
    for name in students:
    print("Now we will input the scores for %s: " % name) 

    while question_number <= number_of_questions:
       questionScore = float(raw_input("Score for question # %d: " % 
           question_number))
       question_scores_preTest[name] = questionScore
       question_number = question_number + 1
    return question_scores_pretest
```

I'm trying to have this while loop go through a limited set of question numbers defined by number_of_questions.  Currently number_of_questions is set to 10.  So I would like to input the score for question #1, question #2 etc.  all the way to 10.  However, it keeps going to 11, 12, 13, 14... as an infinite loop.  Is my indentation wrong or is it the order I have for the flow?
Thanks!

Comment: where is `number_of_questions` defined? what's its type?

Comment: btw `question_scores_preTest` naming inconsistent

Comment: number_of_questions is defined before this as a global variable:

Comment: number_of_questions = raw_input("Please input the number of questions on the assessment: ")

Comment: @George You appear to be comparing a number against a string. I can't remember what that'll cause in Python, but probably nothing good. I'd expect an error though.

Comment: @Carcigenicate works in python 2 (see my answer). That's the main issue.

Comment: I'm using python 3, but it still works??

Comment: you're _not_ using python 3. `raw_input` is python 2 only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're incrementing your value, "infinite loop" can only occur:

- if `number_of_questions` is very high
- if you're using python 2, and you got `number_of_questions` through `raw_input` *without* converting it to `int` (`raw_input` returns a string whatever the value is)

demo (python 2):

```
>>> 12 < "10"
True
```

note that in python 3 you get an "unorderable types: int() < str()" exception instead (it's for the best, that would have helped to find your error)

So from your last comment, the quickfix is:

```
number_of_questions = int(raw_input("Please input the number of questions on the assessment: "))
```

Comment: Thank you!   I forgot to convert it to an integer - I was looking for the problem in the wrong place.  Thanks again!

Comment: And I'll fix the inconsistent typo :)